# Angular IO: Return of promises

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise

I have a problem with my system.

Basically, I have an entity:

```
import { Produto } from "./produto.model";
import { Empresa } from "./empresa.model";
import { Mensagem } from "./mensagem.model";

export class Nfe{

    public codNfe: number;
    public numeroNfe: number;
    public dataEmissao: Date;
    public valorTotal: number;
    public empresa: Empresa;
    public produtos: Array<Produto>;
    public mensagens: Mensagem;

    constructor(){};
}
```

And a service:

```
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

      public getNFE(numero: string): Promise<Nfe>{
        return this.http.get(`${URL_API}nfe?numeroNfe=${numero}`)
          .toPromise()
          .then((response: any) => {
            return response.json()
          });
      }
```

And a view:

```
export class ExibirNfeComponent implements OnInit {

  public nfe: Nfe;
  constructor(private service: NfeService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getNFE('26180406057223028939650050000133071050336085')
    .then((nfe: Nfe) => {
      this.nfe = nfe;
    })
  }

}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">Id: {{nfe.codNfe}}</div>
</div>
```

When I am calling my screen, I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'codNfe' of undefined

I assume this happens because it takes some time for the service to respond. I need a way for the view to wait my object to become full.

How can I do that?

Update 1

I put some console logs:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Begin OnInit')
    console.log(this.nfe)
    this.service.getNFE('26180406057223028939650050000133071050336085')
    .then((nfe: Nfe) => {
      this.nfe = nfe;
      console.log(this.nfe)
    });
    console.log('End OnInit');
  }
```

Look the results: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLtV3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the nfe variable in your template before it is defined.

```
{{nfe.codNfe}}
```

That is what the message is telling you. You have to do a check before you use it. There is a shortcut for that by adding a `?`.

Change that part to

```
{{nfe?.codeNfe}}
```

The questionmark will check if nfe is undefined or empty and only accesses codeNfe if it is not.

Comment: But now, I have other problem. 
My variable doesn't update on the screen.

Comment: Did you made sure that the variable was loaded? Add a console log statement in your then block.

Comment: Yes, I do. 
I will update the question with the console results.

Comment: if by any chance the service returns the same object (even if with modified properties), then there will be no change detection, assuming you have ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. If this is the case you have to inject a ChangeDetectorRef and call .detectChanges() or .markForCheck on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
It was simply my JSON framework.
The structure was a matrix and my application received an object.

Thanks for everything